# exchange the value of two variables

Tags: visual-c++

Write  appropriate C++ code to  exchange  the  value of  two  variables  (for example first Variable and second Variable) 
while
a.Using one additional variable
b. Without using any additional variable

Comment: So, what's the question!

Comment: using programming C++ visual studio!

Comment: Is it right???

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void main ()
{
 int variable1=0;
 int variable2=0;
 cout<<"Enter the Variable 1"<<endl;
 cin>>variable1;
 cout<<"Enter the Variable 2"<<endl;
 cin>>variable2;
 variable1 = variable2;  
 cout<<"Variable1 = "<<variable1<<endl;
    variable2 = variable1-variable2;
 cout<<"Variable2 = "<<variable2<<endl;
 variable1 = variable1-variable2;
 cout<<"Variable3 = "<<variable1<<endl;

}

Comment: Please, take a minute to read about how to ask a question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The a.answer:

```
int a = 1, b = 5, c;
c = a;
a = b;
b = c;
std::cout << a << b;

system("pause");
```

The b.answer:

```
int a = 1, b = 5;
a = a + b;
b = a - b;
a = a - b;
std::cout << a << b;

system("pause");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```cpp
int a = 1, b = 5;
std::swap(a, b);
```